# Problem installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

After installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on my Computer today the grub menu didn't show up and i only saw a screen with "Realtek PCI" searching for DHCP and then i came back to my bios menu.
So it was not possible for me to boot Ubuntu after installation. I already tried a new installation and downloaded elementaryOS with the same result after installation.

Before this i had a working Arch Linux installation on my PC.

I already tried "boot repair" and changing the boot order in my BIOS.
Does anyone has an idea what i could try next or am i missing an important point during the installation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which mode you installed Legacy or UEFI?

Comment: UEFI i think. Before installing the system there was an UEFI warning.

Comment: May be that will be the issue. Check this [Ubuntu Official Document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).